# RedShift: insert values if/else

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to insert data with conditions:

```
IF public.dags_works.target_table != 'value'
 UPDATE public.dags_works SET target_table = getdate() where target_table = 'value';
 return 1;
ELSE
 INSERT INTO public.dags_works values ('value', '2008-01-01 00:00:00'); 
 return 0;
END IF;
```

I have get an error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF" Position: 1

As I understand RedShift doesn't support if-else conditions for my situation. But how I can change the query?

Comment: Is your code running inside a User-Defined Function or Stored Procedure? `IF` is not a valid SQL command outside of these contexts. What is `public.dags_works.target_table`?

Comment: public.dags_works.target_table - scheme.table.column. I run this code without User-Defined Function or Stored Procedure. How I can rewrite the query?

Comment: What are you wanting that IF statement to evaluate?